# How do I get the Current ServiceSecurityContext on the server side when using WCF?

Tags: wcf, iis

I have a client app that can upload some data via a WCF service. 
I have the client app setup some credentials so the service can authenticate the user using some membership provider.

I'm having some issues getting SSL (https) working at the moment so I tried just simplifying the config by setting security modes to none. When doing so the context is always null on the server.

Does that mean I need to setup SSL in order to access ServiceSecurityContext.Current on the server side?

Comment: Yes, if you have no security at all - what do you need a SecurityContext for?? You only get a SecurityContext if there's some kind of security in place

Comment: true yeah thought so. i've just been having issues getting WCF to jive with SSL since i put this service on a number of boxes. it gets confusing with all the configurations and certs etc.

Comment: well i think i've figured out the security config for my localhost; hosting a WCF service in IIS locally and having a client consume it locally over SSL. Seems to be authenticating but i can't run a debugger on the service. VS claims the service isn't configured proper but i can nav to the svc page no problem. So i run some traces from the server to see if the context has anything and it's still null.

Comment: i thought maybe the context was null because my iis was setup to allow anonymous access. if i disable anonymous access i get Security settings for this service require 'Anonymous' Authentication but it is not enabled for the IIS application that hosts this service". So it looks like if i use transport security it must allow anonymous access but i can't get at a valid user context on the sever side post-authentication...

Comment: well it's working now. i didn't do anything to change anything. at least i don't think so. but i seem to have a valid context on the server side. the odd thing is that my visual studio debugger won't let me debug my service saying it's not properly configured.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
ServiceSecurityContext.Current.PrimaryIdentity.Name;
```

Comment: I had some issues where the Current context was null on the server side. This seems to have been due to my IIS settings not requiring SSL.